# import schema from another schema in nest.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose, import, nestjs, schema

I am working with Nest.js and MongoDB. There is a common schema defined.

common.schema.ts:

```
import { AbstractDocument, ObjectIdType } from '@app/common';
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { SchemaTypes } from 'mongoose';

@Schema({
  timestamps: true,
  versionKey: false,
})
export class Common extends AbstractDocument {
  @Prop({ type: SchemaTypes.ObjectId })
  studentId: ObjectIdType;

  @Prop()
  studentName: string; 

  @Prop()
  studentNumber: string; 

  @Prop()
  grade: string; 
}
export const CommonSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Common);
```

Need to use the above schema values in the below schema:

student.schema.ts:

```
import { AbstractDocument, ObjectIdType } from '@app/common';
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { SchemaTypes } from 'mongoose';

@Schema({
  timestamps: true,
  versionKey: false,
})
export class Mark extends AbstractDocument {
  @Prop({ type: SchemaTypes.ObjectId })
  subjectId: ObjectIdType;

  @Prop()
  subjectName: string; 

  @Prop()
  totalMarks: string; 
}

export const MarkSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Mark);
```

The common schema is included in student module.

student.module.ts:

```
import { Student, StudentSchema } from './student.schema';
import { Common, CommonSchema } from '../common.schema';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      {
        name: Student.name,
        schema: StudentSchema,
      },
      {
        name: Common.name,
        schema: CommonSchema,
      },
    ])
  ],
  controllers: [StudentController],
  providers: [StudentService, StudentRepository],
})
export class StudentModule {}
```

After this I don't know what to do. I need the final data to be inserted as like below:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('643f8a6773a92fb1552e4c89'),
  studentId: ObjectId('643f8a6773a92fb1552e4c90'),
  studentName: 'xxxyyy',
  studentNumber: 12345,
  grade: 2,
  subjectId: ObjectId('643f8df1885133b26167166c'),
  subjectName: 'English',
  totalMarks: 55
}
```

How to do that in Nest.js?

Need some valuable help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can use inheritance.
change

```
export class Mark extends AbstractDocument
```

to

```
export class Mark extends Common
```

Hope this helps :)